# Why do I need to change MATLAB path in order to read the files?

Tags: matlab

I am reading 50 files from a folder as follows:

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('/home/user/Desktop/MTP/schemes/o33smnpimp/data/', '*.dat'));
```

My problem is until & unless I have same exact folder opened as path in MATLAB path (one above the path window) this command won't work. What is the reason behind this? Actually there are multiple schemes and every time I need to run a particular scheme, I have to go to the data folder of that particular scheme. How can it be solved?

Comment: What do you mean by schemes? Are those some functions?

Comment: Are you saying that the command above doesn't work or that when you try to run or read the files/functions returned by it that you get an error? Please provide any error messages (the full message in clouding line numbers) and any other code. And what is meant by "path in MATLAB path" and "path window"? Is the latter the Set Path GUI (i.e., `pathtool`) found under Home > Environment > Set Path ?

Comment: @Divakar Basically I have 10 types of data generated by different schemes. Now all of these are in different folders like o1exp, o1imp, o33smnpimp etc. These folders further contain data folder in itself which contains 50 dat files each. What I need to do is read all these dat files in single MATLAB file and plot the results. Your earlier solution solved my problem if I just want to read from a single folder. But in the case of multiple folders it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you can get the list of files using the full path like you have but you ALSO need to specify the full path when you use it. For example, try changing your code to:

```
baseDir = '/home/user/Desktop/MTP/schemes/o33smnpimp/data/'; % <--- will use this twice
list_of_files=dir(fullfile(baseDir, '*.dat'));

for ind = 1:length(list_of_files)
    myFilenameFull = fullfile(baseDir, list_of_files(ind).name);  % <---- must use fullfile here too!
    D1 = getData(myFilenameFull, 'stuff');
end
```